# What's the meaning of these batch commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I just want to know the meaning of this instructions in detail:

```
"%0\\ \n cd %0\\.. \n cd /d %0\\.. \n mup.exe"
```

I searched about it but I didn't find anything.
in my program a method is called which makes a batch file in the path of the 'programmer TNM' installation:

```
createbatchFile(new File(batchFile));
```

the implementation of the method is:

```
private void createbatchFile(File file) throws IOException, Exception{

    if(file.exists())
      file.delete();
    File f = new File(file.getPath(),file.getName());
    f.deleteOnExit();

    char[] cmd = "%0\\ \n cd %0\\.. \n cd /d %0\\.. \n mup.exe".toCharArray();
    writeToFile(cmd , file);
    return;
 }
```

And the above code makes a

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that's not batch. Well, it's sort of batch. It's batch as written by some other language; you can tell because batch doesn't use `\` as its escape characters, and it wouldn't know what to do with the `\n` character. This appears to be some language creating a batch file, but without more code it's hard to tell.

`%0` is the command line argument for the script itself.
`\\` will write a literal `\` to the output file
`\n` is a newline character
`cd %0\\..` *would* move to the parent directory of the current directory... if %0 was a valid directory path. But as I said before, %0 is the script itself, and that's saying `cd script.bat\..` which won't do anything
`cd /d %0\\..` is the same thing, but with the `/d` option, which allows for `cd` to move between drives, like from C: to D:. But again, this won't actually do anything because the syntax is incorrect.
`mup.exe` runs mup.exe - not sure what this is, but it's what gets run

Comment: I added a part of code, I don't know if some where else is vague or not. @SomethingDark

Comment: @shakiba - Nope, it's exactly as I thought; a different language attempting to create a batch script via another program. My original explanation still stands. As for the code itself, if you know where the script is running from and you know where mup.exe is, it may be a better idea to simply call the full path to mup.exe (or at least call `..\..\mup.exe`) instead of the `cd` commands.

Comment: It's really strange, because it has nothing to do with drive d! but when i remove the part cd /d %0\\.. it doesn't run the mup.exe @SomethingDark

Comment: Do you have any idea what's cd/d%0.. is doing?! I said the project doesn't have to do with drive D!

Comment: @shakiba - I never said that `/d` _requires_ a move between drives, simply that it _enables_ that option. Moving from C: to D: was merely an example. Like I said in my answer, if `%0` was a directory, `cd /d %0\\..` would move from the current directory to its parent directory. HOWEVER, since `%0` is a file, the command does nothing, as `script.bat\..` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Although you've said that the script works correctly, so now I'm rather curious about _why_. But since it's working, in this circumstance, `cd /d %0\..` is effectively equivalent to `cd %0\..`

Answer (score 0):

`%0` in batch files is the name of the script itself if `SHIFT` command is not used.
As in your example theres `%0\\` I suppose there's a created directory named after the batch and this is a command passed to another command.

`%0\\..` should mean the upper directory.

Without sharing more your code no more can be said.

Comment: I added a part of code, I don't know if it is still vague.

Comment: @shakiba - is this working? As I see it creates a batch file with but this `%0\\` will cal the batch with `\` at the end which could cause an error.Rather you need to remove the `%0\\ \n ` part.